# Can't see upvotes and downvotes for questions and answers

Tags: support, down-votes, up-votes, votes

In StackOverflow the user can see the number of upvotes and downvotes

[image]

when he clicks the total number of votes for a question/answer (between the upvote/downvote arrows).

But this is not possible in Workplace. Is there any reason for it? I thought this was available for all stack exchange sites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have 1000 reputation on Stack Overflow.

From [the privileges](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) page:

> Awarded At: 1,000 Reputation
>
> What are Established Users?
>
> Established users are those who have been participating on the site
> for a fair amount of time. They gain the following privileges.
>
> They may view the vote counts on posts An expanded usercard will show
> additional profile information How do I view vote counts?
>
> Voting scores, as displayed, are the sum of the up and down votes on a
> post. Vote counts are the individual up and down votes that make up
> the score.

If this really bothers you, check out [this extension](https://stackapps.com/q/3082/22322).

Comment: yep, you're right. I've been participating so many years in stack overflow that I assumed this was for everyone, and not a feature unlocked. So I will have to gain here 1000 reputation ? That will be hard haha. Thanks!

Comment: @Gonzalo.- check out the extension I just added, it lets you view that everywhere.

Comment: I will. Thanks again !